# How to call class attributes for a child class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, attributes

The question is a little misleading, sadly. I can't quite find a good way to ask my question.
I'm making a small text-based rpg.
I'm stuck on how to say "hey, this enemy has spawned, load its attributes."

I have:

```py
class Entity:
    def __init__(self, ID, name,  maxhealth, health, strength, defence, strBuff, defBuff):
        self.ID = ID
        self.name = name
        self.maxhp = maxhealth
        self.hp = health
        self.Str = strength
        self.Def = defence
        self.strBuff = strBuff
        self.defBuff = defBuff

class Monster(Entity):
    pass

Goblin = Monster(0, "Goblin", 10, 10, 5, 2, 0, 0)
goblin = {"ID": Goblin.ID, "name": Goblin.name, Goblin.hp: 10, Goblin.Str: 5, Goblin.Def: 2, Goblin.strBuff: 0, Goblin.defBuff: 0}
Satyr = Monster(1, "Satyr", 5, 5, 3, 6, 0, 0)
satyr = {"ID": Satyr.ID, "name": Satyr.name, Satyr.hp: 5, Satyr.Str: 3, Satyr.Def: 6, Satyr.strBuff: 0, Satyr.defBuff: 0}
```

And I can't quite find a way to say something like.

```
Monster.hp -= Player.Str
```

I can only seem to do it with specified enemies.

Comment: I guess `Goblin` should be a subclass of `Monster` and `goblin` an instance of `Goblin`. Then you can simply do `goblin.hp -= player.str`.

Comment: What is the intended difference between `Goblin` and `goblin`?  Why is one a `Monster` class instance, and the other is a dictionary?

Comment: I actually have just that, my problem is that it wouldn't apply to a satyr.  I want to take the current monster's hp and subtract from it, not just a goblin's

Answer (score 2):

Your are creating two `goblin` and `satyr` dictionaries. They are not needed, as they contain the same data than the two objects `Goblin` and `Satyr`.

Instead, you can work with those two objects directly.

Below, I added a `__str__` method to print information about an Entity, and I also added a `hit` method for one Entity to hit another.

Is this answering your question?

```py
class Entity:
    def __init__(self, ID, name,  maxhealth, health, strength, defence, strBuff, defBuff):
        self.ID = ID
        self.name = name
        self.maxhp = maxhealth
        self.hp = health
        self.Str = strength
        self.Def = defence
        self.strBuff = strBuff
        self.defBuff = defBuff

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + " has " + str(self.hp) + "HP"

    def hit(self, otherEntity):
        print(self.name + " hits " + otherEntity.name + "!!")
        otherEntity.hp -= self.Str

class Monster(Entity):
 pass

goblin = Monster(0, "Goblin", 10, 10, 5, 2, 0, 0)
satyr = Monster(1, "Satyr", 5, 5, 3, 6, 0, 0)

print(goblin)
print(satyr)
satyr.hit(goblin)
print(goblin)
print(satyr)
goblin.hit(satyr)
print(goblin)
print(satyr)
```

Output:

```
Goblin has 10HP
Satyr has 5HP
Satyr hits Goblin!!
Goblin has 7HP
Satyr has 5HP
Goblin hits Satyr!!
Goblin has 7HP
Satyr has 0HP
```